# Higher or lower game Java

Tags: java

I am struggling to make a higher or lower game. Here are the rules:
 1. The program has to draw the first playing card from 1-13. can do that using " card = randomNumbers.nextInt(13 - 1 + 1) + 1; "
 2. The value of the card is then displayed to the user e.g. 10. It should ask the user whether they think the next card would be higher or lower.
 3. Next Card is drawn. Program should display whether user was right or not.
 4. Another card is drawn until their guess is incorrect.

I'm not sure whether a do loop is best and have a for loop within as I need the card to refresh every time whilst determining whether it was higher than the previous card. If someone could give me some pointers it would be very much appreciated. Thanks :)

As a starting point, I have done:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HigherOrLower {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int card;
        String userResponse;

        Random randomNumbers = new Random();

        card = randomNumbers.nextInt(13 - 1 + 1) + 1;  
        System.out.println("Card is " + card);  

        System.out.print("Higher or Lower?");
        userResponse = scan.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: `13 - 1 + 1` - wouldn't that just be `13` or did I miss my math lessons? ;)

Comment: I'd not bother which type of loop to use at this stage. You'll need a loop for sure but just choose what you think is appropriate and try it. If you have specific problems ask here, if you want your code reviewed when it works ask at [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Oh, and don't forget to use your debugger while developing.

Comment: As @Thomas has stated you will for sure need a loop. Using a `while` or `do-while` loop is strictly up to you, but maybe it will help if you understood the differences between the two (just in case you're not familiar with them). Really, the only difference between `while` and `do-while` loops are where the conditions are checked. `do-while` loops always iterate at least once since the condition is checked at the bottom. `while` loops have their condition checked immediately, so may be skipped over altogether. Rarely do I see `do-while` loops used anymore, but it's really up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your input matches with the card drawn. This is not an exact code. But hope it will gve you an overview of what should be done.

```
int terminate = 0;

do {
        Random randomNumbers = new Random();

        card = randomNumbers.nextInt(13) + 1;  
        System.out.println("Card is " + card);  

        System.out.print("Higher or Lower?");
        userResponse = scan.next();
        cardNext = randomNumbers.nextInt(13) + 1;

        if ((String.valueOf(userResponse.charAt(0)).equalsIgnoreCase("H") && cardNext > card) ||
         (String.valueOf(userResponse.charAt(0)).equalsIgnoreCase("L") && cardNext < card)) {
           System.out.println("Correct!");
        } else {
           System.out.println("You lost");
           terminate = 1;
        }
} while (terminate != 1);
```

Comment: You can pull `Random randomNumbers = new Random();` out of the loop. Also, simplify `13 - 1 + 1` to just `13`.